# create adjacency list from a file

Tags: java, file, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Graph1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int linecount = 0, ec = 0;
        int nbin = 0, cbin = 0;
        int[][] data = new int[6][6];
        String e = "e";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        String newfile = sc.nextLine() + ".txt";
        File file = new File(newfile);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while ((scan.hasNext())) {
            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(scan.nextLine());
            if(t.nextToken().equals(e)) {
                ec++;System.out.print("ec.." + ec );
                nbin = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
                cbin = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
                data[nbin][cbin] = 1;
            }
        }
```

input file is:

```
jjjjjjjjj
e 1 3
e 2 5
e 3 4
e 4 1
e 5 3
```

i want to create adjacency list from the file entries.my code gives adjacency matrix.i heard that there are specific functions for adjacency list in java please help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start by downloading [Open Data Structures](http://opendatastructures.org/). If you click on the link labeled `java sources` you will get an archive file containing the source (and compiled class files) of several data structures. Included among them is a java implementation of [AdjcencyLists](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-java/12_2_AdjacencyLists_Graph_a.html).